# Change electrical switch of the ignition switch on a Deawoo Cielo (1995)

Tags: electrical, ignition-switch, daewoo

The car is still starting flawlessly but some accessories like the radio or the clock don't always work.

I noticed that pushing the key deeper in the ignition would make the radio start, but releasing it will make it stop most of the time.

I had a look at the ignition switch (see pictures bellow) and found out that the electrical switch (the black thing on the left) is loose by more than one millimeter. Sure enough, when I keep it in position, everything is working as expected.

[image: ignition switch]

[image: ignition switch closeup]

I managed to unplug the electrical connector, but I couldn't find how to remove or re-attach the black part to the main part of the ignition switch (see the third picture).

[image: ignition switch without the plug]

My questions are:

- How to disassemble the black part from the ignition switch
- How to reassemble it in place (since it works when I push it in place, if I can just replace it correctly it should work without need to replace it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the front of the aluminium body of the ignition switch, it looks like there is a small screw that will need removing.

Looking at the photo of an ignition switch for your car on amazon - [http://www.amazon.com/Ignition-Switch-Daewoo-Cielo-Part/dp/B013XF3P1E](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013XF3P1E)

It looks like there will also be a similar screw on the back of the body that will also need removing.

I cant guarantee that this is the correct part for yours, but it looks like it.

I think, that if you open it up and clean the contacts your problem will go.  If not, I would replace the switch.

Comment: Thanks! As a mater of fact, the second "screw" on the back of the body isn't a real screw but a sliding pin which was disengaged in my car. I pushed it back in place and it fixed the issue. I would have prefer a real screw since it's likely the pin will disengage itself again after some time but now I know how to fix it.

Comment: You could wrap some tape around it to stop the pin sliding out.